# jQuery jScrollPane - Making vertical scrollbar appear for a portion of the page without specifying height

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I regularly use the [jQuery jScrollPane plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com) to add custom scroll bars to page sections.  I have run into a situation where I want to use the plugin to display a vertical scroll bar for the main content area of a page.  Since the content can have varying height I cannot specify a fixed height for this area and therefore the plugin does not display the vertical scroll bar even when it should.

I have uploaded my full HTML, CSS and JavaScript code at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/xaLBB/) for demonstration of the problem.  The area with lots of text should display a jScrollPane vertical bar but it doesn't.  I know that if I add a height to the .scroll CSS class, the scroll bar will start appearing.  However, different users will have different screen resolutions and therefore the height of the content area will vary, preventing me from specifying a height for the content area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a specified height, the vertical overflow will not work. You can always set the height of the scrollable area dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(setScrollable());
$(window).resize(setScrollable());

function setScrollable()
{
   $('.scroll').css('height', $(window).height() - $('#header').height());    
   $('.scroll').jScrollPane();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this css if you want in the body/section of the page you need

```
overflow-y:auto;
```

Comment: Setting overflow without a specified height won't affect it, because the window will always scroll to accommodate the height.

Comment: he won't have to since the height would be inherited. i tried this in jsfiddle and it worked fine.

Comment: Can you post your jsfiddle fork? `overflow-y:auto;` allows the browser window to be scrollable, but doesn't enable the blue/grey jQuery scroller OP is requesting.

Comment: i got what you mean then, i thought it was meant for the browser window as a whole in jsfiddle